# Force xrandr 1.4 usage?

Tags: xrandr, display-resolution, randr

I force enabled xrandr 1.2 with `xrandr --q12`.

How can I force xrandr to version 1.4? I've looked in `man` for information on doing so, but there isn't anything - `xrandr --q14` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RandR protocol version 1.4 is used by default. Therefore you can only force the usage of RandR protocol version 1.2 and 1.1.

To start `xrandr` with the protocol version 1.4, do **NOT** use the `--q12` or `--q1` parameter.

Check your version with

```
$ xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.4.1
Server reports RandR version 1.4
```

Comment: What if I just forced 1.2 usage though? to revert it back?

Comment: There is nothing to revert. Use without `--q12` for 1.4

Comment: what do you mean - without?